# Why is ferror() returning EPERM when there is no space left on device - I would expect ENOSPC

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I wrote a C++ application on linux using cstdio. It contains one function which should overwrite a whole device with random data. It is given a file name, creates blocks of random data in memory and writes them one after the other using fwrite() to the file.
If the device is full, the function should return. If there is a different write error, it should throw an exception.
So when an error occurs I ask ferror() and want to recognize if this is a "disk is full" -  a different error.
I would expect to get ENOSPC when the disk is full. But the function writes to the disk and when it's full, the value returned by ferror() is 1 (which is EPERM).
perror on the other hand prints the correct "No space left on device".
Is this a bug in my C++ libs? Or is EPERM the correct error code?
If it is the correct error code, is EPERM only returned when the disk is full and therefore suitable for recognizing this specific error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ferror` only tells you whether there was an error on the stream.  To see what the error actually was, you have to examine `errno`.

`perror` examines `errno` which is why it prints the correct error message.

Answer (score 1):

`ferror` is not supposed to return an `errno` value; it just returns a non-zero value if a stream error occurred. You should inspect `errno` directly.

Answer (score 1):

ferror just indicates that an error occured, something you should already know if you tested the result of the function you used to write (or the result of fclose).  And POSIX mandates that those functions (fwrite, fputc, fprintf, fclose) set errno at a value describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in my C++ libs

More likely to be a bug in the kernel or the device driver. But neither is likely.

Answer (score 0):

May be because on `ext` filesystems part of them by default is reserved for `root`. So, there may be space left but the current user can't use it.

`man mke2fs`

```
   -m reserved-blocks-percentage
          Specify the percentage of the filesystem blocks reserved for the
          super-user.   This  avoids  fragmentation, and allows root-owned
          daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to  function  correctly
          after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the
          filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.
```